# How to login using FB api as a page?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Or if it's impossible, how can I switch to a facebook page using fb api after login?

Answer (score 2):

The classic way to use the facebook API as a page is to:

1. request the `manage_pages` permission from a user
2. call `/me/accounts` to get the list of pages, and their access tokens
3. use the access tokens to make API calls on the page's behalf

Check out the facebook documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

There is a new way to use facebook as a page. If you sign up for AS A PAGE from the facebook homepage with company@example.com, then you can use those credentials to sign in to apps. This seems like a very new and undocumented way of doing things, and it breaks certain API functionality, such as the `/me` connection.

Comment: How would you know which specific page you're giving access to?

Comment: @Elton - You give access to all pages or none of them. There is no way to restrict which pages an app can manage with the `manage_pages` permission

Comment: Exactly. You wouldn't know which page's data do you need.